# Correct preposition in sentences below

Tags: prepositions

Is there any preposition I can use instead of same as or like in sentences below? I mean Can I say ;

> 1) I wish to buy a car of/from yours.

Or should I say ;

> 2) I wish to buy a car of the same as yours.

But I want to learn especially if first sentence correct or not .

Comment: _A car of yours_ means a car that you own, probably one of several. Do you mean that you want a car _like_ the other person's? You would have to say _a car the same as yours_ or _a car of the same make [or model] as yours_.

Comment: Yes I want to say “the car same as yours“ . Can use “of” instead of “same as” like car of yours or car from yours ?

Comment: No - as I explained, _I want to buy a car of yours_ would mean _I want to buy one of the cars that belong to you_. _A car from yours_ is not correct English, but it would suggest the same meaning.